I don’t know what to buy!
My roommate asked me to buy some stuff from the grocery store.
“What am I supposed to get from the grocery store, sir?” I replied.
“Man, get out and just buy the dang groceries, WILL YOU!?!” shouted my roommate.
What am I supposed to buy?

Hint:

 Look at the tags, and study the dialogue.


An item to buy is

 man get out -> mangetout - peas picked young with edible pods.


Correct! Well done!

I know this is correct but it still irks me a bit - surely you could never misinterpret "mangetout" as "man get out" because they have completely different pronunciations?

@TakingNotes this is [tag:wordplay], not [tag:pronunciationplay]…

Well, the question is phrased as a conversation...

I already know this is wrong:
you should get:

 Cherry-flavored Mochi

your roommate is asking you to buy

 the dang groceries -> the dango cherry -> cherry-flavored dango, also known as mochi


Sadly incorrect, but welcome to Puzzling.SE! I must’ve accidentally included a red herring!

You were on the right track though, the answer is somewhere in the same quote.

Is it, perhaps...

 a mango?

Your roommate said to

 'Man, get out (go) and get the dang groceries!'
 = Man + go = Mango


Sadly incorrect. Welcome to puzzling.SE!
(Lol I accidentally said chat.SE initially)
